# Asp.net mvcpaging - @Ajax.Pager missing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pagination

I am using this a MVCPaging nuget package which can be [found here](http://nuget.org/packages/mvcpaging)

intergrating ok, compilation ok too, however at runtime, error at the line: ***@Ajax.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount,"AjaxIndex", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divCategoryList" }).***

It seems that the application cannot recognised the **@Ajax.Pager** method, no intellisense for **Pager** neither after typing @ajax.

I am using this [tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/07/06/using-mvcpaging-in-asp-net-mvc-apps.aspx) , may be I have to implement somehow the properties Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount ?

Am I missing something ?, can you point me out to the right direction ?

Thanks

Comment: please show the error you are getting here

Comment: I guess that there are missing extensions for Ajax calls from the MVC Paging library extensions

Comment: also have you used the Step 1 of your link ? using MvcPaging;

Comment: the error is: No overload for the method Pager is taking the argument number 5.

Comment: I integrate it via nuget explorer, it should be same version both isn' t

Comment: ??? that means you are getting the Pager() method right and then this error

Answer (score 0):

With the error message you are getting as written in comments,

I think you are getting the Pager() method right ?

and then I feel you are not overloading the method Pager() properly, First try only with the basic parameters as mentioned in the example link you posted, if that still doesnt work then it could be a reference issue

Comment: As there are no intellisense from the method, I guess that I am missing some helpers extensions files, I have just the reference of MVCPaging and no extensions files, is it normal ?

Comment: I finally figured out how to make it works, this is the right syntaxe for it: @Html.Pager(1, 1, 2, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "gridcontainer"}).Options(o => o.Action("AjaxPage"))

Answer (score 0):

From version 2 of MvcPaging, @Ajax.Pager is missing and replace with @Html.Pager.
Only one method with all functionality.

See [Martijn post](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2012/04/23/mvcpaging-2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="pager">
                                    @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber, Model.TotalItemCount,new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "gridcontainer"}).Options(o=> o.Action("index").DisplayTemplate("Bootstrap3Pagination"))
                                </div>
```

If you use Bootstrap3Pagination. The pager look good